# Need Help to develop tridion mobile site with existing blueprint

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Tridion consultant has developed the tridion website for my company with below blue print (Blue print 1). Now company required to develop the tridion mobile website  with the existing content(website content), but with new look and feel(Blueprint 2).

Tridion consultant has given the basic training in tridion to modified the content and create the new page template and component template(I just copy the existing to create the new templates). I do not have idea in tridion mobile site. My Company want me to develop the tridion mobile site.

I have planned to use responsive web design to develop the tridion mobile site. So it automatically adjusts the screen in the entire mobile and tablets. Please provide your suggestion and guide to develop the tridon mobile site.

Blue print 1

Empty parent -->   Content  --> Website Design --> Website

Blue Print 2

Empty parent -->   Content  --> Website Design --> Website

```
                  |
                  |-------> Mobile Design --> Mobile site
```

Comment: This might have done better as a question on Webmaster's exchange, (or on the TridionWorld forum). But I do see a question in "if doing responsive design, what should my BluePrint look like?" Basically, you're using the same publication for the site, so the answer is "no changes to the SDL Tridion BluePrint" required. Blue print 1 is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the training you've already had didn't cover BluePrinting in any depth. Getting your BluePrint correct is very important, as poor choices may constrain your future design decisions. I would suggest two things:

1. Get professional advice now on the details of how to extend your current BluePrint
2. If you are going to be doing this kind of development in future, consider taking the relevant training modules yourself.